# is it possible to monitor websocket communication using aws xray

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, aws-xray

I followed the Aws tutorial for setting up a node.js project just fine, however it seems like it can only trace http requests.

```
var AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('http'));
var http = require('http');
```

My project will aslo start utilizing websocket connections apart from the http that already were already set up, but I can't set up Aws xray to also capture my websocket calls (messages after the handshake is established).

The documentation doesn't touch anything websocket related, though.

Is it possible to setup xray to trace websocket connections as well?

Answer (score 1):

The X-Ray SDK for Node does not support patching websocket calls at this time. However this does seem like a perfectly valid use case and you are more than welcome to open a [pull request](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/pulls) with a new patcher for web socket connections. Alternatively, you could create your own custom (sub)segments as described in [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master/packages/core#developing-custom-solutions-using-automatic-mode) sample code to trace the calls manually.